# Reading From A File Which Contains Unicode Characters

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, iostream, ifstream

I have this huge file which contains unicode strings at the beginning (first ~10,000 character or so) 
I don't care about the unicode part, parts I'm interested aren't unicode but whenever I try to read those parts I get `'='`, and if I were to load the entire file to char array and write to to some temporary file (without altering the data) with `ofstream` I get incorrect data actually all I get is a text file filled with `Í` If I were to remove the unicode part manually everything works fine, So it seems `ifstream` cannot deal with streams which contains unicode data, but if this assumption is true, is there any way to work on this file  introducing a new library to my project?

Thanks,

EDIT: Here's a sample code, program reads from this file which contains characters (some, not all) that can't be represented in ASCII.

```
ifstream inFile("somefile");
inFile.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
size_t size = inFile.tellg();
inFile.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);
char *book = new  char[size];
inFile.read(book,size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  cout << book[i] << " " << i << endl; //book[i] will always be '='
}
ofstream outFile("TEST.txt");
outFile.write(book,size);
outFile.close();
```

Comment: There are many Unicode libraries able to read such files. (e.g. inside Qt or inside Glib from GTK).

Comment: Yes, I know I could use Qt but I don't want to introduce a new library to my project. Also, I don't care about the unicode parts I only care about the parts that comes after the unicode characters (the parts that can be represented in ASCII)

Comment: Which of the several representations of Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, etc.) does the file use?

Comment: "if this assumpion is true" --- The assumption may or may not be true depending on your platform, compiler, and Unicode representation (UTF-8 etc). Sharing some or all of the above would help.

Comment: it uses UTF-8, but I also comes with the ANSI version too (neither works with the ifstream)

Comment: One out of three, OK. I don't know what this "ANSI" thing is. UTF-8 can be read by anything that can read a stream of 8-bit bytes. Any byte that is less than 128 corresponds to an ASCII character. This happens automatically more or less everywhere. You either have an unusual platform, or doing something unusual in your code. Can you post a short self-contained example?

Comment: Your code works here. If you are viewing the output in a terminal window, this has no meaning. The terminal emulator can attempt unicode conversion on its own, it may lack needed fonts, etc. Redirect to a file and look at it in a hex editor, it's the only way to be sure of its contents.

Answer (score 4):

Keith Thompson's question is very important. Depending on which Unicode encoding, writing a small C routine that reads (and discards) the Unicode characters can be trivial, or slightly more complex.

Supposing the encoding is UTF-8, you will have a problem determining when to stop discarding because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so any time you encounter an ASCII char, you might be tempted to say "this is it, we're back in ASCII land" and the next char still might be still outside the ASCII range.

So you need to read the file and determine where the last character>127 is. Anything after that is plain ASCII -- hopefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I really don't understand is that how ifstream fails the read ASCII when there is a non-ASCII character on the file. Because to my knowledge, UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII (first 255 character have the same int representation) but alas, reading the file with ifstream and saving it with ofstream screws every charcter in the file.

Comment: Actually, ASCII is compatible with UTF-8 -- first **128** codepoints are the same -- but UTF-8 is not compatible with ASCII. Anything above 127/0x7F is not ASCII.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry, that's what I meant, but still I'm not getting the correct results If I were to use Qt then I don't have any problems(QString supports unicode characters). But I can't understand why cout fails to print everything in the array (whether they can be represented in ASCII or not) as long as I have a character that cannot be represented in ASCII I'll get '=' for every single character. (I get correct results once I remove the Unicode charcters at the beginning.)

Answer (score 0):

A text file is generally in just one encoding utf-8, utf-16 (big or little endian) or utf-32 (big or little) or ASCII or other ANSI code pages. Mixing of encoding is only possible in some custom ways.

That said, you will have to read both the data that you need and that you don't in the same encoding. If you know the format is utf-8 you could, depending on what you are going to do with the data, read the file as a binary file into char buffer piece by piece. Then you could API(s) like strnextc (on windows. equivalent API must be available on other platforms) to move character by character on the buffer. Once you reach the end - you could move the balance to the front of the buffer and load the rest of the buffer from the file.

In fact you could use the above approach in general for any encoding. But for utf-16, you could try using wifstream - provided the endianess of the file and the platform you would be running on is the same. And you need to check if the implementation of wifstream is good at handling change in endiness and is able to take care of BOM (byte order mark) - 2 byte sequence ("FE FF" or "FF FE") that is generally present at the beginning of a file - leave alone surrogate pairs.